# threading work results are unexpected - java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

i am new at multi threading.
i am working on a program to read a file with many records (3 million integer numbers) into some linked list and then some threads work on each list and calculate the sum of the list, finding the maximum and minimum. then the main thread compares the child thread results and display the final results.

program work with this command:

> compute -f file_path -t threads_Number

Now the problem is when i run the program with one thread it takes less time than some threads.

my CPU is core i7.

this is some time results:

(Threads     : duration) --> (1 : 16) , (2,3 : 32) , (4,5,6,7 : 47) , (8,9 :  31) ... (17,18,19,20 :   16)

the project have 2 projects:

Worker class:

```
public class Worker implements Runnable {

    private List<Integer> records;
    private long[] res;
    private String name;

    Worker(String name, LinkedList<Integer> list, long[] res) {
        this.records = list;
        this.res = res;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long sum = 0;
        int max, min;

        if (records != null && records.size() > 0) {
            max = min = records.get(0);

            for (Integer num : records) {
                sum += num;
                if (num > max)
                    max = num;
                if (num < min)
                    min = num;
            }

            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long duration = endTime - startTime;

            res[0] = sum;
            res[1] = max;
            res[2] = min;
            res[3] = duration;

            System.out.println(name + "\t->\ttime:\t" + duration + "\t, Records:\t" + records.size());
        }
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //read command and get inputs:
        System.out.println("Welcome to my app : ");

        while (true) {

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String command = scanner.nextLine().trim();
            if (command.startsWith("compute")) {
                command = command.substring("compute".length() + 1);
                args = command.split(" ");
            } else {
                System.out.println("wrong command.. this app only support 'compute'");
                exit(1);
            }

            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>(); //-p processes , -f filepath
            for (int i = 0; i < args.length - 1; i += 2)
                map.put(args[i], args[i + 1]);

            File txtFile = new File(map.get("-f").trim());
            final int threadCount = Integer.parseInt(map.get("-t").trim());

            ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>> lists = readFile(txtFile, threadCount);
            if (lists == null) {
                System.out.println("Error: can not found txt file..");
                exit(2);
            }

            long[][] results = new long[threadCount][4];
            Thread[] thread = new Thread[threadCount];

            for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
                thread[i] = new Thread(new Worker("thread " + (i + 1) ,lists.get(i), results[i]));
                thread[i].start();
            }

            boolean isAlive = true;
            while (isAlive) {
                isAlive = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++)
                    isAlive |= thread[i].isAlive();
            }

            long[] res = null;
            for (long[] result : results) {
                if (res != null) {
                    res[0] += result[0];
                    if (res[1] < result[1])
                        res[1] = result[1];
                    if (res[2] > result[2])
                        res[2] = result[2];
                    if (res[3] < result[3])
                        res[3] = result[3];
                } else {
                    res = result;
                }
            }

            if (res != null) {
                System.out.println("sum : " + res[0]);
                System.out.println("max : " + res[1]);
                System.out.println("min : " + res[2]);
                System.out.println("duration : " + res[3]);
            }

        }
    }

    private static ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>> readFile(File txtFile, int procCount) {
        if(!txtFile.exists() || txtFile.isDirectory())
            return null;

        ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0; i < procCount; i++)
            arrayList.add(new LinkedList<>());

        try {
            int index = 0;
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(txtFile));
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                arrayList.get(index).add(Integer.parseInt(line));
                index++;
                if(index == procCount)
                    index = 0;
            }

            return arrayList;
        }   catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, threads are costly. Iterating through 3 million integers and doing basic arithmetic operations is very fast, and starting and coordinating threads has a big cost that probably doesn't make it worth using threads. Second, you're using a busy loop to constantly check if the threads are done. Use Thread.join() instead.

Comment: I would start replacing the costly busy waiting while (isAlive) { ... } with thread[x].join() for all threads.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not use **Executors**?

With the *argument* Integer.parseInt(map.get("-t").trim()) you create a **Pool of Threads**. And isAlive is not longer required. And the *results* the concept of **Future**.

[Threads Pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)

[Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)

[Executors - Threads Control](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html)

[Examples](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your 'out of the ordinary' results most probably have to do with optimizations done by the  [JIT compiler](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/underst_jit.html)

Your code is doing 'kind of a benchmark' here, with a configurable number of threads.
For such benchmarks it's recommended to use the [JMH framework](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/).

In case you are just learning multi-threading, I recommend you avoid measuring the performance of you code. There are lots of things to be considered when doing benchmarks, and failing to do them right will result in unexpected result, such as the one you are seeing now.